# Graph partitioning for two graphs at once

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, operations-research, set-partition

Assuming I have a graph with nodes that are of two classes ("circles" and "boxes") and that have connections between all circles and boxes ("black") and within each node group ("red"), where intra-class weights ("red") must be positive while inter-class weights can be any real number: I would like to find a unknown number of clusters in the graph where a cluster must consist of at least one "circle" and one "box". In the graph below the following clusters would be expected:

$$
\big\{[a],[b],d,e,f\big\}, \ \ \big\{[c],g,h \big\}
$$

[image]

$$V = \{[a],[b],[c],d,e,f,g,h \}$$

$$
E_1 =\begin{bmatrix}
  & d & e & f & g & h\\
[a]& \ddots  &  & &  & \vdots \\ 
[b] &  &  &\ddots  & & \\ 
[c] & \cdots &  & & & \cdots  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\\
E_2 =\begin{bmatrix}
& [a] & [b] & [c]& d & e & f & g & h \\
[a] & \ddots &  &  & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
[b] & \ddots & &  & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
[c] &  &  & &  0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
d & 0 & 0 & 0&  &   &    &   & \vdots  \\
e & 0 & 0 & 0&  & \ddots   &    &   &  \\
f & 0 & 0 & 0&  &   &    & \ddots   &  \\
g & 0 & 0 &  0& &   &    &   &  \\
h & 0 & 0 &  0& &   &  \cdots   &   &  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The inter-class graph is defined as $G_1=(V,E_1)$  while the
intra-class graph is defined as $G_2=(V,E_2)$.

Are there algorithms that let me jointly cluster such a graph? I was thinking of merging the two graphs and simply apply a multi-cut. However, this might violate my condition of clusters consisting of at least one element per class.

What would be a sufficient optimization formulation for this problem?